# Защита от подделки почты

Tags: spf

Хочу защитить домен от подделки писем с других серверов. На домене вообще не используется почта. Я указал запись ДОМЕН TXT запись "v=spf1 -all". При подделке почты SPF пишет PASS с другим IP. Что не так делаю?

Comment: Видимо, без информации о конкретном домене, конкретном IP и конкретном способе проверки конкретно ответить не получится

Comment: Ну сама SPF запись корректно же указана?

Comment: Ну вроде бы, но без информации о конкретном домене я например всё равно не могу проверить, что указано действительно именно это

Comment: А вообще если вы проверяли сразу после добавления записи, то может быть просто кэши днс не успели почиститься, и сейчас спустя час почта возможно уже не ходит

Comment: DNS давно уже обновлены.